# TeXLive 2013 (on Linux/Ubuntu) - tcfmgr & fmtutil not found

Tags: errors, texlive, ubuntu

When I try to update packages via `tlmgr` (or run `fmtutil-sys --all` directly), TeXLIve reports:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/fmtutil: 395: /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/fmtutil: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/texconfig/tcfmgr: not found
fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found.

kpsewhich fmtutil.cnf reports "/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/web2c/fmtutil.cnf"
```

This was a clean install of TeX Live 2013, so I'm not sure what went wrong (or how to fix it).

Comment: Have you tried to call `tlmgr check all`?

Comment: There is no `<YEAR>/texmf` tree any more, so it's quite strange `fmtutil-sys` points to that directory. It's possible you have set some TeX-related variable in the environment. What does `env|grep TEX` print?

Comment: @PaulGaborit: it exits unsuccessfully (status 1).

Comment: @egreg: 
TEXMFLOCAL=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFMAIN=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf

Comment: @BeSlayed Remove the setting of those variables from your environment. They are useless and the second is wrong, actually the most likely candidate to be the culprit.

Comment: @egreg: That did indeed fix it (after a reboot). Thanks.

Comment: [Though `tlmgr check all` is still unhappy for some reason.]

Comment: @BeSlayed It's quite normal that `tlmgr check all` finds some ‘inconsistency’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set the variables `TEXMF` and `TEXMFLOCAL` in your environment, which is not unrecommended.

The TeX programs in the TeX Live distribution are able to figure out the right value for these variables at runtime, by reading the `texmf.cnf` files they find in the appropriate locations. Such locations are determined by asking the system where the running binary is located. In a typical (vanilla) TeX Live 2013, binaries are stored in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/<arch>
```

(where `<arch>` depends on the machine and running operating system). From asking the operating system, the running program knows the value of `SELFAUTOPARENT`, in this case `/usr/local/texlive/2013` and tries to read a `texmf.cnf` file there, if existent. Then it reads

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

and this is where your setting failed. The TeX programs never override the value of a variable that has already been set. So the second `texmf.cnf` file doesn't set `TEXMF` to the correct value for the 2013 distribution, which should be

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist
```

while TeX Live 2012 set it to `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf`. This is where the thing went wrong.

Moral of the story: never set the `TEX...` variables in the environment, with the possible exception of `TEXINPUTS`. Other `...INPUTS` variables can also be set, check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks again. I don't recall why I had defined those variables originally, but I had set them a number of years ago and kept "updating" them for new TeXLive versions.