# XeLaTeX on centos 7 does not work

Tags: xetex, linux, texmf

I tried to compile some trivial LaTeX files with the shipped XeLaTeX on centos 7:

```
$ xelatex trivial.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt
/usr/bin/mktexfmt: line 395:
/usr/share/texlive/texmf/texconfig/tcfmgr: No such file or directory
fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found.
I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'!
$ rpm -q texlive-xetex
texlive-xetex-svn26330.0.9997.5-32.el7.noarch
$ cat trivial.tex
\documentclass{article}

\title{Hello World!}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Upon reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124047/texlive-2013-on-linux-ubuntu-tcfmgr-fmtutil-not-found) I tried the following

```
TEXMF=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist xelatex trivial
```

but it did not help. How can I fix it?

Comment: If it tells you which file is missing, you can generally search the package repo for the package that provides it, and install that. In this case, that wouldn’t work because the `,fmt` files are not listed as provided by any package, so you’d have to search for the `xelatex` pattern.

Comment: The other missing file, `fmtutil.cnf`, is in `texlive-kpathsea`, so make sure that is installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to install the pseudo-package `texlive-collection-xetex` to make it work.

Here is the authoritative reference: [TeXLive on Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with getting XeLaTeX to work on CentOS 7. After numerous trials, I found a solution for a working xelatex, by installing the tinytex package (without root privilege) :

1. Install tinytex : https://yihui.org/tinytex/
2. Make the environment to find tinytex's xelatex first on your path, such as adding: export PATH="~/bin":$PATH in your .bashrc
3. Using the tinytex manager to search and find your missing component needed by latex: https://yihui.org/tinytex/#maintenance
4. Install the package containing the missing component in step 3; repeat 3 and 4 till all dependent components are installed
5. Now, compiling LaTex document just works!

Comment: Welcome to the site! This seems to be a nice answer to a different question?

Comment: Thanks for the greetings! Actually tinytex has xelatex in its collection of tools, so I will rephrase my answers to indicate this is a solution to get xelatex working on centOS 7 without super user rights etc. (I had root right on my workstation with centOS, but still couldn't get it working for my jupyter notebook tex file compilation).