# Can't use xelatex because don't find xelatex.fmt

Tags: errors, texlive, linux

I do that.

```
xelatex main.tex
```

And then, xelatex only returns messages below.

```
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt
tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found (ls-R missing?).
fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found.
I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'!
```

I using Cent OS 7 and install Texlive 2013 from yum by the command that

```
sudo yum install texlive-*
```

and it works.

When I met the problem, I run the command

```
sudo mktexlsr
```

to create ls-R file. But it not helped to solve the problem.
Do you have some ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124047/5763. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: Also: Please [install the latest TeXLive 2016](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/5763).